# Como preparar um objeto Java para ser enviado (com valores)?

Tags: java

Tenho que enviar um objeto Java serializado, eu já tenho esse método que recebe um objeto e envia, minha dúvida é como setar os valores no objeto, meus dados estão no banco, basta eu pegar os dados do banco setar no objeto e enviar? Nunca fiz isso, por isso tenho essa dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa que você deve fazer é garantir que sua entidade esteja implementando a interface Serializable do pacote java.io.Serializable;

Após isso, você setará os valores do seu objeto e com ele pronto você fará a serialização de fato, transformando-o em um conjunto de bytes.

Este é um exemplo de uma classe Cliente, sendo persistida e obtida:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
//A classe deve implementar Serializable

public class Cliente implements Serializable {
    private String nome;
    private char sexo;
    private String cpf;

    public Cliente(String nome, char sexo, String cpf) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.sexo = sexo;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(char sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.nome + " / " + "Sexo: " + this.sexo + "\n" + "CPF: "
                + this.cpf;
    }

}
```

Abaixo segue a main que executará a gravação e a leitura de objetos em um arquivo.

```
public class ExemploStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Cria o objeto serializado
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente("Glaucio Guerra", 'M', "0000000001");

        try {
            //Gera o arquivo para armazenar o objeto
            FileOutputStream arquivoGrav =
                    new FileOutputStream("/Users/glaucio/Desktop/saida.dat");

            //Classe responsavel por inserir os objetos
            ObjectOutputStream objGravar = new ObjectOutputStream(arquivoGrav);

            //Grava o objeto cliente no arquivo
            objGravar.writeObject(cliente);
            objGravar.flush();
            objGravar.close();
            arquivoGrav.flush();
            arquivoGrav.close();
            System.out.println("Objeto gravado com sucesso!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Recuperando objeto: ");

        try {

            //Carrega o arquivo
            FileInputStream arquivoLeitura = new FileInputStreamc:/saida.dat ");

            //Classe responsavel por recuperar os objetos do arquivo
            ObjectInputStream objLeitura =
                    new ObjectInputStream(arquivoLeitura);

            System.out.println(objLeitura.readObject());

            objLeitura.close();

            arquivoLeitura.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Objeto gravado com sucesso!
>
> Recuperando objeto:
>
> Glaucio Guerra / Sexo: M
>
> CPF: 0000000001